# How to display table only after when it's data is inserted from php

Tags: php

I have a table in MySQL database which its name is courses. it consists of id, course_code, course_title and credit_hours. I also have a form which data can be inserted into this table using PHP. I want to display a table consisting the data of the courses table in PHP but only after a data is inserted into it and not show it if it is empty and has no data like it does not even exist. I have tried using HTML table then showing data but if the table is empty still the table will be displayed and that is not what I want. hope I am clear.

Comment: share your code what are you doing

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Make select request from DB, then you can use the [`num_rows`](https://www.php.net/mysqli_num_rows) on the dataset to check the number of rows returned.

Something like this:

```
if($results->num_rows === 0)
{
    echo 'No results';
}
else
{
    //output results from database and display datatable
}
```